# How to check return value of a function at runtime while debugging in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

```
void exampleFunction(int a, int b)
{
    int c=sum(multiply(a,b),c);
}
```

While debugging this exampleFunction, is there a way i can check the return value of multiply(a,b) function at run time. I do not want to put any System.out.println statements. Suggest a way while debugging code in android studio.

Comment: Why don't you want to put any system outputs?

Comment: There are a lot of functions in the code used such as and i dont want to put system outputs everywhere. I think in debugger settings there would be something for setting watchpoints which should use directly functions

Comment: I don't believe you can see intermediate results in the debugger, but if you step into `sum()`, you can see the value of the first parameter, which is the value you're after.

Comment: sum() is the example, there could be "if" condition where i can not step in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## This is a common question for whoever starts from zero. It's not hard, so follow these steps and you will reach it.

Step 1: add breaking point at

```
int c=sum(multiply(a,b),c);
```

Step 2:debug it and stop at breaking point

Step 3:right click and you will see

[image]

Click "Evaluate Expression"

Step 4: input `multiply(a,b)`

Done! Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks.. it helped

Comment: What if my method changes the state of the program. Does the "evaluate expression" on that method change the state when run?

Comment: @Stan you can test by yourself. It's not hard.

Comment: I didn't comment for my sake, but for making the answer more complete.

Comment: i agree with @Stan - this approach should come with warnings, because it's not actually showing what was returned, it's re-executing the method.  for example if my method returns a unique value each time it's called.

Answer (score 1):

I just found another way also, we can also click on add watch and directly put the function multiply(a,b), it will keep on showing that result in watches whenever that function and "a,b" are in scope